# Dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, dropdown

I want to make a dropdown filter, which when you clicks on a certain value it only shows the images with that specific class. Can anyone help me? For the menu code see down

```
<select id="filterOptions2">
  <option value="active"><a href="#" value="all">All</a></option>
  <option value="MT">MT</a></option>
  <option value="secretariaat">Secretariaat</a></option>
  <option value="schade">Schade</a></option>
  <option value="acceptatie">Acceptatie</a></option>
  <option value="hypotheken">Hypotheken/Financiele planning</a></option>
  <option value="pensioen">Pensioen</a></option>
</select>
```

And this is an item, wrapped inside a wrapper

```
<div id="teamwrapper">
    <div class="item schade">
      <img src="<?php echo $view->getThemePath() ?>/assets/images/dummy.png" alt="Arthur" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">
        <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
          <div class="hvrbox-text">
            <h5>Naam</h5><br><p>Titel</p>
          </div><!--End text-->
        </div><!--end layer top-->
      </div><!--End item-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change the src according to the option value.

Comment: you tagged jquery so i would do somethin like 
    $('#filterOptions2").on('change' function (){ $('.'+$(this).val()).show()});
asuming that the images at hidden by default.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this one.

```
//Dropdown change event
$('#filterOptions2').on('change',function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value=='active'){
    $('div.item').show();
  }else{
    $('div.item').hide();
    $('.'+value).show();
  }
});
```

Please check below working snipet.

```js
$('#filterOptions2').on('change',function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value=='active'){
    $('div.item').show();
  }else{
    $('div.item').hide();
    $('.'+value).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filterOptions2">
  <option value="active"><a href="#" value="all">All</a></option>
  <option value="MT">MT</a></option>
<option value="secretariaat">Secretariaat</a></option>
<option value="schade">Schade</a></option>
<option value="acceptatie">Acceptatie</a></option>
<option value="hypotheken">Hypotheken/Financiele planning</a></option>
<option value="pensioen">Pensioen</a></option>
</select>

<div id="teamwrapper">
  <div class="item schade">
    <img src="<?php echo $view->getThemePath() ?>/assets/images/dummy.png" alt="Arthur" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">
    <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
      <div class="hvrbox-text">
        <h5>Naam</h5><br><p>Titel</p>
      </div><!--End text-->
    </div><!--end layer top-->
  </div><!--End item-->
  <div class="item acceptatie">
    <img src="<?php echo $view->getThemePath() ?>/assets/images/dummy.png" alt="Arthur" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">
    <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
      <div class="hvrbox-text">
        <h5>Naam-2</h5><br><p>Titel-2</p>
      </div><!--End text-->
    </div><!--end layer top-->
  </div><!--End item-->
  <div class="item acceptatie">
    <img src="<?php echo $view->getThemePath() ?>/assets/images/dummy.png" alt="Arthur" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">
    <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
      <div class="hvrbox-text">
        <h5>Naam-3</h5><br><p>Titel-3</p>
      </div><!--End text-->
    </div><!--end layer top-->
  </div><!--End item-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use this all images hide on click. The images arent on display: none by default. Im kinda new to Jquery so any suggestions?

Comment: Please check my updated answer..  I have resolved that already.. and please check the updated snippet as well..

Comment: Still no luck @Rahul Patel. The images dont seem to load, only on all it does the trick

Comment: You mean initially all images are hidden.. and all gets loaded when all option selected from dropdown?

Comment: No the images arent hidden initially, but when I select for example schade all images disappear, and when I go back to all they appear. So thats the only link working atm

Answer (score -1):

Provided that your `<div class="item schade">` is an example of a div linking up with the `<option value="schade">`, the following code should work.

```
$('#filterOptions2').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == "scahde") {
    //handle showing the element here.
    }
});
```

Comment: I dislike this suggestion due to missing flexibility - dont want to add a new if for each new case now, do I?